# How to change 3D trajectory animation to scatter version in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

How to change 3D trajectory animation to scatter version in matplotlib?

At first, I followed the manual of Matplotlib, and I made a trajectory animation of particles.
It worked well, and I could modify random data to my own *.csv files.

However,
I also need a "scatter animation", without trajectory lines like molecular dynamic animation.
Of course matplotlib library has scatter function, but for that, I should change all the data types.

In case of trajectory, it has complicate array and lists. And I don't want to make big change of the types.
(Final result is a list of array which include several arrays.)

I write down the manual of Matplotlib.

https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_3danim.html

I wonder if I can change trajectory to scatter without changing data type.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YsF0.png)